# Word in haiku - sugara

Tags: meaning, suffixes, haiku

This is a well known haiku:
Meigetsu ya
Ike wo megurite
Yo mo sugara

I cannot understand the meaning and grammatical form of "sugara". Is it from "sugaru" (to finish)? Why does it end in "a"?

Comment: Thank you. I could not find this word in my dictionary of Classical Japanese.

Answer (score 4):

In this context, [すがら](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/117460/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%E3%82%89/) roughly means "throughout". Therefore,  [夜{よ}もすがら](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/228442/meaning/m0u/) means something like "throughout the night" or "all night long".

So, the subject of the haiku was walking around the pond the entire autumn night.